# VLC cross compile in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: xml, sax, vlc, libxml2

While preparing third party lib in VLC Cross compile for windows I am getting this error 
`SAX1 support in libxml2 is required. enable it or use expat instead` 
how to enable SAX1 support?? or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
--with-sax1
```

while using  ./configure